# Multiple databases using same domain models with Spring Boot and Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

In my Spring Boot project, I am writing a service to import **selected** data from one environment to another. (e.g. copy one record to dev to prod)
As far as i [read](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-multiple-databases), to configure multiple datasources, i need to create different JPA repositories and domain models. But since the db structures are identical in each datasource, it will be just code repetition. Is there a better practice to copy data from one db to another with Spring Data JPA?

Comment: Wouldn't native replication provided by the database or an ETL tool be a better candidate for something like this?

Comment: I don't think so, since the end user is going to select the records to be imported.

Comment: Please add such constraints to the question itself, otherwise, it remains too broad, unclear and open to interpretation.

Comment: It should be possible to use the Spring [`AbstractRoutingDataSource`](https://spring.io/blog/2007/01/23/dynamic-datasource-routing/) to read from one database (`DataSource`) and write to another using the same repository. Try the linked Spring tutorial with Spring Data JPA configuration.

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this without adding a bunch of complexity of multiple data sources would be to create 2 different spring profiles (one for each data source) then start 2 instances of the application, one with each spring.profile. Read the data from one, then pass the data to the second (via REST or whatever) to insert it. This also creates re-usable services for each data source if you needed access elsewhere.

There ARE ways to use multi-data sources, but I've always found they've been overly complex for what I've needed.